# How do I set my AWS Lambda provisioned capacity to zero in off hours?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm using the Serverless framework (serverless.com) and it looks like I can save some pretty serious money by only scaling up the provisioned capacity of my Lambda functions during business hours (9am-5pm, 40 hour per week) and then down to zero during off hours. My application isn't used very much in off hours, and if it is, my users are okay with cold starts and it taking longer.

In my serverless.yml, I have functions declared such as:

```
  home_page:
    handler: homePage/home_page_handler.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: homePage
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: authorizer_handler
    provisionedConcurrency: 1
```

I also have a Lambda that runs on a regular basis to set the provisioned capacity of the other Lambdas in the account depending on the time of day. In that Lambda if I call:

```
await lambda.putProvisionedConcurrencyConfig({
    FunctionName: myFunctionName,
    ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: 0,
    Qualifier: "provisioned",
  }).promise();
```

Then I get this error:

```
Received error:  ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value '0' at 'provisionedConcurrentExecutions' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value greater than or equal to 1
    at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12) {
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2021-08-14T17:45:48.932Z,
  requestId: '8594fad6-d5dd-4a00-adca-c34f9d38b25e',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 77.81562781029108
}
```

On the other hand, if I try to delete the provisioned capacity entirely, like this:

```
  await lambda.deleteProvisionedConcurrencyConfig({
    FunctionName: myFunctionName,
    Qualifier: "provisioned",
  }).promise();
```

That works fine, but when I try to deploy my function again in off hours (which is the norm), CloudFormation errors out with:

```
No Provisioned Concurrency Config found for this function (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ProvisionedConcurrencyConfigNotFoundException; Request ID: 75dd221b-35d2-4a49-80c5-f07ce261d357; Proxy: null)
```

Does anybody have a neat solution to turn off provisioned capacity during some hours of the day?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-aws-lambda-provisioned-concurrency-for-recurring-peak-usage/ - how it would be done via Cloudformation - not sure if serverless has a direct equivalent

Comment: have you considered using CloudCustodian ?

Comment: @RomanCunningham I tried that but it has the same problem. The AutoScaling removes the provisioned concurrency in off hours and then I get the error above during deployment.

Comment: @VarunChandak if I had to move to a new framework, which would be far more expensive than the money I'm saving here, I would move to AWS's stuff.

Comment: @RyanShillington that might be true, but custodian deploys lambda and cloudwatch events.

Answer (score 2):

After some thinking, if you're still committed to Lambda as the compute solution, I think your best option is to manage provisioned concurrency outside of the Serverless Framework entirely.

You've already got an orchestrator function which will enable provisioned concurrency, you could try removing `provisionedConcurrency` from your `serverless.yml` file, adding another method in your orchestrator to disable provisioned currency in the evenings, and verifying that you can deploy when your orchestrator has set your functions to either state.

If you're willing to throw away your orchestrator function, AWS suggests using [Application Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-aws-lambda-provisioned-concurrency-for-recurring-peak-usage/), which is very useful for exactly what you're doing. (hat tip to @mpv)

That being said, Lambda isn't particularly well suited to predictable, steady-state traffic. If cost is a concern, I'd suggest exploring Fargate or ECS and writing a few autoscaling rules. Your Lambda code is already stateless, and likely is portable and has pretty limited networking rules. There are other forms of compute which would be dramatically cheaper to use.

Comment: I'm not convinced that Serverless that's at fault here. I think it's CloudFormation. CloudFormation is what's throwing the error.

Comment: While ECS may be cheaper, they also require management (ie. rotating passwords, updating virus scanners, more security issues, less fine grained permissions, etc). We spend ~$50/month right now on 10+ environments. That's going to balloon into $400/month with provisioned capacity, but I couldn't possibly hire somebody to manage my ECS machines for the difference in costs, and Fargate would be about the same price.

Comment: @RyanShillington Serverless framework compiles down to CloudFormation, which is where your error is coming from.

Comment: As a former Serverless employee (and Serverless Framework contributor) I agree wholeheartedly. If the benefits you're getting from Lambda outweigh the costs, that's great, and this is a worthy endeavor. I interpreted your initial comment as the additional cost being untenable, and worth revisiting.